# Реализация анимации линии

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, html5, css3

Подскажите, как можно реализовать анимацию линии как здесь: [пример](http://aic.ru/work/site/639/)

Comment: Не та линия, что при загрузке анимируется, а желтая, в самом кейсе

Answer (score 2):

16 вариантов анимации при загрузке на CSS3 и jQuery
[http://www.coolwebmasters.com/animation/2393-css3-jquery-loading-animations.html](http://16%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20CSS3%20%D0%B8%20jQuery)

Анимация загрузки при помощи CSS3
http://www.webmasters.by/articles/html-coding/517-css3-loading-animation-loop.html

Comment: Не та линия, что при загрузке анимируется, а желтая, в самом кейсе